# Rule::unique not working while update | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

Hi I am using Request to validate my form.

```
listingId = 20
categoryType ='listing-category'
```

I have tried two ways to validate the form. First is

```
'title' => 'required|min:2|max:255|unique:terms,title,'.$listingId.',id,type,'.$categoryType,
```

And the second one is

```
if($this->method() != 'PUT')
    {
        $uniqueTitleValidation = Rule::unique('terms')->where('type', $categoryType);
    }
    else
    {
        $uniqueTitleValidation = [];
        $uniqueTitleValidation = Rule::unique('terms')->ignore($listingId)->where('type', $categoryType);
    }
```

and in validation

```
'title' => [
                'required',
                'min:2',
                'max:255',
                $uniqueTitleValidation
            ],
```

while creating a new entry it Is working fine. But ignoring the type I guess while updating and throw me already exists error.

This is my DB table

[image]

Now as you can see I want to check for listing-category. But I think it also checking for category type.

**Note: I am using laravel 5.8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below example is cleaner and should work.

```php
$uniqueTitleValidation = Rule::unique('terms')
    ->where(function ($query) use($categoryType, $listingId){
            if($this->method() != 'PUT') {
                return $query->where('type', '=', $categoryType);
            }

            return $query->where([
                ['type', '=', $categoryType],
                ['id', '<>', $listingId] // ignore this id and search for other rows
            ]);
});
```

Comment: Well this worked for me. It means ignore doesn't work or what?

Comment: When you put a where clause you are simply scoping search to some rows I guess ignore will not work. @jayantrawat

Comment: Yes that is the case, I guess too. BTW thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule in your UpdateRequest under App\Http\Requests

Just add the below code.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
            'title' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            Rule::unique('terms', 'title')->whereNull('deleted_at')->ignore($this->listing),
        ],
    ];
}
```